# Can data in a cte become lower than their actual value

Tags: sql-server

This is my problem I am trying to understand how a column which has values higher than 1000 is reduced to values below 1000 in my CTE that is the table transaction-id

This is my code:

```
with productionCTE(quantity, transactionid, productid) as
(
     select 
         quantity, ProductID, max(transactionid)
     from 
         Production.TransactionHistory
     group by
         Quantity, ProductID
) 
select 
    quantity, transactionid,
    productid = (select max(transactionid) as MAX_UNIT from productionCTE)
from
    productionCTE
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the columns you declare for the cte is this:

```
with productionCTE(quantity, transactionid, productid)
```

and then the main body of the cte:

```
select quantity,ProductID,max(transactionid) 
from Production.TransactionHistory 
GROUP BY Quantity,ProductID
```

So the `quantity` is ok, but `ProductID` which is selected 2nd becomes `transactionid` in the results because this is what you declared as 2nd column in the cte header and vice versa for the 3d column.
So what you see as `ProductID` is actually `transactionid`.
Change the declaration to:

```
with productionCTE(quantity, productid, transactionid)
```

Then here:

```
select QUANTITY,TRANSACTIONID ,
PRODUCTID  = (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONID) AS MAX_UNIT FROM productionCTE)
FROM productionCTE
```

why are you assigning the max `transactionid` to `productid`?
Is it because you get wrong results with the cte?
The only thing that would make sense is this:

```
select QUANTITY,PRODUCTID ,
  TRANSACTIONID = (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONID) AS MAX_UNIT FROM productionCTE)
FROM productionCTE
```

although I don't know what you are trying to do.